# Traveling on H4 visa in pregnancy

Tags: visas, usa, h1b-visas, pregnancy

I've got H1b visa and I will be traveling to USA in October, my wife (H4 visa) will travel in December (if I get clarity on the assignment length).

My wife is 3 months pregnant & by December she will be 5 months. If doctor allows then she will travel from India to USA because there is no one here to take care of her. So my questions are:

1. We are going for stamping next week; do I have to specify her pregnancy? I didn't find anything related to it in the documents.
2. When she will travel in December, will USA immigration stop her to enter?
3. I really have no intention for grabbing citizenship for my child. I just want both to be healthy and I want to be with them when they need me. So, if she will be asked (may be because of her belly by 5th month), how can she justify her visit?
4. Is there anything which I have to do to make her entry smooth? One thing I know is insurance. Any other thing which I have to take care.

P.S.: I am trying hard to cancel my trip but it seems that it is so critical that if I skip this I might have to lose my job as well.

Comment: If your child is born in the US your child will be a US citizen.  There is no way to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Can I visit the U.S. while pregnant and what are the risks involved?**
>
> Although there are no specific regulations prohibiting pregnant foreign nationals from entering the U.S., entry is allowed or denied at the discretion of the admitting U.S. Customs and Border Protection (CBP) Officer. If the CBP Officer determines that you are likely to become a ward of the government (meaning that the government must provide medical care because you do not have medical coverage), you can be denied entry.
>
> When determining if you will be allowed to enter the U.S., CBP Officers take into consideration the date your child is due for delivery and the length of time you intend to stay in the U.S. In addition, they want evidence that you have sufficient medical insurance to cover any medical necessities while you are in the U.S. and that you intend to return home.
>
> If it is determined that you do not have sufficient medical insurance to cover any unexpected or expected medical care while in the U.S., you can be denied entry. Additionally, if you are pregnant and entering the U.S. at a border port of entry via vehicle, be aware the radiation detection portals deployed at the ports do not emit any radiation, and do not present a hazard to you and your unborn child.

Source: **[CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/882/%7E/can-i-visit-the-u.s.-while-pregnant-and-what-are-the-risks-involved%3F)**

After that, all you need to do is to check with your airline about their policy of allowing travel in the late stages of pregnancy. All airlines have their own policies about the maximum allowed period before they refuse.

Comment: "why not?" Because it can make life terribly complicated for the child.  If the child is born in the US, the child will be unable to enter the US without a US passport, but obtaining a US passport will cause the child to lose Indian citizenship.

Comment: @phoog Actually that's not my concern. I am just more worried about travel and health of mother and child. Getting a US passport/Indian passport won't be a difficult task.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/122787/3

Answer (score 1):

One primary concern will be how you will pay for the birth - especially if it is premature or there are complications. Giving birth in the USA and most travel insurance plans won’t cover it.

I would be prepared to show that you have insurance but that you also have access to at least $20,000 or more in funds to pay the bill. This is because of (perhaps apocryphal) stories of immigrant women giving birth and then leaving the hospital without paying.